# Windows Store - App can't be installed because your PC might not meet some of the requirements

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

We develop an app which is on the Windows Store and targets Windows 8.1 in it's build. The app is fully submitted to the store and works perfectly on Windows 10 devices. However on all Windows 8.1 devices we are receiving the following message when trying to install the app from the store:

**Purchase Error - Sorry, this app can't be installed because your PC might not meet some of the requirements. Go to the app's description page to check for any requirements listed under details.**

The apps description page has no requirements other than supported processors of x86, x64, ARM. There is nothing special about the requirements for the app and we are not using anything out of the ordinary.

The app works fine if it is side loaded or remote debugged onto a Windows 8.1 device. It just seems that the Windows Store for whatever reason is incorrectly blocking its download onto any Windows 8.1 devices.

Has anyone any ideas? We have attempted a wsreset.exe without success.

Thanks,

Comment: What does the device family availability list under the Package page in the dashboard contain? Did you select the Windows 8/8.1 box after you uploaded the package in dashboard?

Comment: Hi Daisy, 

In our device family availability we have a blue 1 under both Windows 10 Desktop and Windows 8/8.1. 

There is also a box with a check in it above Windows 10 Desktop. All the other Windows 10 options have an unchecked box above them. All the Windows 8 families don't even have an empty check box above them. 

Thanks,